# New tab pdf opening issue in window sytem on live server

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have A code like which is given below that code is working fine with linux system but same when i am trying to open the file in new tab in window system it showing me the blank page instead of downladed pdf in server.

```php
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config'); 
$postData = $request->getPost()->toArray();
$companyData = $this->getTable()->getdata($user_id, $postData['company_id'],0, 8);
$employeeData = $this->getTable()->fetchCompanyEmployeeBasicDetails($postData['emp_id']);

$filename = "deepika-".date('Y-m-d-h-i-s').'-'.$postData['emp_id'];
$pdf = new PdfModel();
$pdf->setOption("filename", $filename);       

$pdfView = new ViewModel($pdf);
$pdfView->setTemplate('application/report/download')
        ->setVariables(array('companyData' => $company, 'employee' => $employeeData))
        ->setTerminal(true); 
$html = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewpdfrenderer')->getHtmlRenderer()->render($pdfView);
$dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$pdfCode = $dompdf->output();
$fileName = $filename.'.pdf';
file_put_contents(ROOT_PATH.'/uploads/data/show/'.$fileName, $pdfCode);
$msg = array('status' => 'success', 'filename' => $fileName);
$result = new JsonModel($msg);
return $result;
```

Same code is working fine with linus system in server but in window system its not working alreday folder permission given to server.i dont know what i am doing wrong here can anyone please help me related to this .thanks in advance

Comment: Any Help related to this ???

Comment: Can you tell which error are you getting?